# difference between db.runCommand({getlasterror:1,fsync:true}) and db.runCommand({getlasterror:1}) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I understand that to getlasterror, it guarantees that the write has been done to a file.

This means that, even the computer power is off, the previous write is still ok.

But what is the use of fsync:true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially getLastError checking for an error in last database operation for the current connection. If you will run this command with fsync option it will also flush data to the datafiles (by defaul mongodb do it each 60 seconds).

More details you can find [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) and [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/fsync+Command)